# Executing shell command in nodejs gives unexpected error

Tags: node.js, sh

I'm trying to execute the following command from nodejs (in Linux)

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('cd "/tmp/export/lessons/4/content/RES-52298196-ce0f-4d91-8aa5-53f4f8e4ecb9/ui" && rm -r !("M345")', (err) => console.log(err));
```

But I get the following output

```
Error: Command failed: cd "/tmp/export/lessons/4/content/RES-52298196-ce0f-4d91-8aa5-53f4f8e4ecb9/ui" && rm -r !("M345")
/bin/sh: -c: riga 0: errore di sintassi vicino al token non atteso "("
/bin/sh: -c: riga 0: `cd "/tmp/export/lessons/4/content/RES-52298196-ce0f-4d91-8aa5-53f4f8e4ecb9/ui" && rm -r !("M345")'
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:441:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:672:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'cd "/tmp/export/lessons/4/content/RES-52298196-ce0f-4d91-8aa5-53f4f8e4ecb9/ui" && rm -r !("M345")'
}
```

However if I try to run the same shell command directly form terminal like this

```
$ cd "/tmp/export/lessons/4/content/RES-52298196-ce0f-4d91-8aa5-53f4f8e4ecb9/ui" && rm -r !("M345")
```

It works fine as expected. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using `find` command instead of `rm` like this:

```
var ui = "folder_i_want_to_save";
var myPath = "/path/to/base/directory";
var cmd = `find . -type d ! -name . ! -name '${ui}' -exec rm -rv {} +`;
exec(cmd, { cwd: myPath }, (err) => console.log(err));
```

And also I have removed the `cd` part of my command and passed as `cwd` parameter.
This is unfortunately a workaround and not a real solution to the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the shell option to `child_process.exec` like `{ "shell": "/bin/bash" }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it does not work